# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, date-conversion

I have below query which i am using in oracle stored procedure where i am getting error as

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE.
```

day_id column is Number datatype and the data is stored in this column like for e.g `20110822` and ltds column is date datatype and value is stored in this column for e.g `08-AUG-17`. Both the column stored the actual date.

In my stored procedure i am putting this query in variable like below:

```
NESS_QUERY:= select t.day_id from M_TIME t 
where TO_DATE (t.day_id, ''YYYYMMDD'') < trunc('''||LTDS||''') and 
TO_DATE (t.day_id, ''YYYYMMDD'') >= trunc(sysdate, ''mm'') - case trunc('''||LTDS||''') when trunc(sysdate, ''mm'') then 1 else 0 end;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (NESS_QUERY);
```

The output of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is below:

```
select t.day_id from M_TIME t 
where TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') < trunc('15-DEC-17') and 
TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - case trunc('15-DEC-17') when trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: where is LTDS coming from? you said it is a column in the table.

Comment: yes its the column in the table i am just fetching the value using select into for this variable and putting this variable into the mentioned select query. From where i am fetching this value its date datatype column

Comment: Why do you have to do that? why not directly use it in select?

Comment: yes we can do that also but as i will use this in many places later on thats why i use select into.. Select LOAD_DATE INTO LDTS FROM JOB_EXE; The LOAD_DATE is date data type and LDTS i have initialize as date type

Comment: i think i am sure whether we have to convert ltds also in this query ..but i think the issue might also coming with quoted string syntax here ?

Comment: `ltds` is a DATE variable, but when you pass it in to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` without explicitly converting it to a string, you are causing an implicit conversion to take place. This conversion will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter (the default value of which is `DD-MON-RR`), hence why you see `trunc('15-DEC-17')` in your output.

Comment: in this case what changes i have to do to make it work ? i am really not understanding

Comment: why are you using dynamic sql anyway?

Comment: @Andrew : I have edited my answer. take a look.

Comment: i am getting error as ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format. I think this error is coming where we are compairing the month column..

Comment: That'll be occurring in your `to_date()` - have you checked to make sure all the values in the day_id column are in `yyyymmdd` format?

Comment: yes i have checked with all values with yyyymmdd format also

Comment: The `trunc` function expects a number or a date, so `trunc('15-DEC-17')` alone will give `ORA-01722: invalid number`. You probably meant `date '2017-12-15'` which is an actual date.

Comment: @William in this case what needs to be done can you please tell ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have any influence over the choice of datatype for this column, please get it changed to be of DATE datatype. That will make things (like the query you're attempting to run) much easier.

As your column is not currently DATE datatype, if you want to compare the contents of the column to a date, you need to convert the column via `to_date()` along with an appropriate format mask. In your case, it looks like the format mask is `yyyymmdd`.

So your query should be something along the lines of:

```
select t.day_id
from   m_time t
where  to_date(t.day_id, 'yyyymmdd') >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - case trunc(ltds) when trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then 1 else 0 end;
```

Comment: but i am still getting same data type error.  When i did DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE while putting the select query in variable in procedure then its returning the output as below : select t.day_id from M_TIME t where TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') < '15-DEC-17' and TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - case trunc('15-DEC-17') when trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then 1 else 0 end

Comment: So, `ltds` is a variable of datatype DATE, and m_time.day_id is definitely a number?

Comment: yes thats correct i use select into to put the variable value in ltds. Select LOAD_DATE INTO LDTS FROM JOB_EXE;  LOAD_DATE is date datatype and i have initialize ltds has date datatype..and m_time.day_id is number. I have updated in my question now

Comment: it is unlikely that you should still be getting the same error message in your actual sql statement (i.e. not the one output by dbms_output.put_line), given what you've said. By explicitly converting m_time.day_id to a date and using the other variables etc as dates, you have covered all your bases.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert `day_id` to `date` before comparison, using `TO_DATE`

```
SELECT t.day_id
  FROM M_TIME t
 WHERE TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') >=
            TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm')
          - CASE TRUNC (ltds) WHEN TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

**EDIT** :
You don't need to use the `ldts` variable in your query, you may save it and use it in other places, but for query you could define it and reuse from cte.

```
WITH l AS (SELECT TRUNC (LOAD_DATE) LDTS FROM JOB_EXE)
SELECT t.day_id
  FROM M_TIME t CROSS JOIN l
 WHERE     TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') < l.LDTS
       AND TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') >=
                TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm')
              - CASE l.LDTS WHEN TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: i am still getting the same error. When i did DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE while putting the select query in variable then its returning the output as below :   select t.day_id from M_TIME t 
where TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') < '15-DEC-17' and 
TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - case trunc('15-DEC-17') when trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then 1 else 0 end

Comment: @Andrew : two things are changed from your original question. I don't know from where `TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') < '15-DEC-17'`  came from and why '15-DEC-17' is passed to `TRUNC`  rather than ldts?

Comment: yes actually i forgot the first condition to mention sorry and i am using this query in my procedure in variable where i am getting this error. When i did DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE for this variable its returning the query as mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: i have updated my question with the information now how i am putting this query in variable and whats the dbms_output the query is returning

Answer (score 1):

below condition causing the error,

```
t.day_id >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

day_id is a number, trunc(sysdate, 'mm')  returns date datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
where (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') < trunc('31-DEC-23') and 
TO_DATE (t.day_id, 'YYYYMMDD') >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - case trunc('01-Jan-23') when trunc(sysdate, 'mm') then ('Yes') else ('No') end
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.